# Laravel- arranging data by ascending which inserted few days ago

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by

I want to arrange my data by ascending. I tried with
**orderBy('roll_number','ASC');**
but I saw that the newly inserted data was arranging but the old data was not arranging. Please help me to fix the problem.
Thanks...

Comment: We really need more details to debug this problem.

Comment: are you using some type of dates where clause?

Comment: Please share your codebase to make it more clear.